# Jquery vertical submenu hiding behind revolution slider

Tags: jquery, slider, z-index

I have a website: http://www.fotofonkeling.nl (in Dutch, but the code isn't ;)

The problem is this: the submenu of the jquery vertical menu is hiding behind the revolution slider. When opening the website and if you select the menu item Foto's, the top items are located under the slider.

I have tried a lot of messing around with the css. Including this:

```
.submenu-container non-mega {
z-index: 999;
}

#dc_jqverticalmegamenu_widget-2-item ul li .sub-container.non-mega li a {
font-weight: bold;
z-index: 99999; !important
}

#rev_slider_1_1_wrapper {
z-index: 1;
}

.rev_slider_wrapper fullwidthbanner-container {
z-index: 1;
}

#rev_slider_1_1 {
z-index: 1;
}
```

All of these show up in the code, but the result remains the same. Can anyone assist me in doing the right thing? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Set z-index to -1 for revolution slider.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Which container should i set it for? the wrapper or the slider itself?

Comment: I have tried both options, no results unfortunately. Any ideas?